# Counting with scipy.sparse

Tags: python, nlp, scipy, sparse-matrix, scikit-learn

I am using the Python sklearn libraries.
I have 150,000+ sentences.

I need an array-like object, where each row is for a sentences, each column corresponds to a word, and each element is the number of words in that sentence.

For example: If the two sentences were "The dog ran" and "The boy ran", I need

```
[ [1, 1, 1, 0]
, [0, 1, 1, 1] ]
```

(the order of the columns is irrelevant, and depends on which column is assigned to which word)

My array will be sparse (each sentence will have a fraction of the possible words), and so I am using scipy.sparse.

```
def word_counts(texts, word_map):
    w_counts = sp.???_matrix((len(texts),len(word_map)))

    for n in range(0,len(texts)-1):
        for word in re.findall(r"[\w']+", texts[n]):
            index = word_map.get(word)
            if index != None:
                w_counts[n,index] += 1
    return w_counts

...
nb = MultinomialNB() #from sklearn
words = features.word_list(texts)
nb.fit(features.word_counts(texts,words), classes)
```

I want to know what sparse matrix would be best.

I tried using coo_matrix but got an error:

> TypeError: 'coo_matrix' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

I looked at the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix) for COO but was **very confused by the following**:

> Sparse matrices can be used in arithmetic operations ...
>   Disadvantages of the COO format ...
>   does not directly support: 
>   arithmetic operations

I used dok_matrix, and that worked, but I don't know if this performs best in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try either `lil_matrix` or `dok_matrix`; those are easy to construct and inspect (but in the case of `lil_matrix`, potentially very slow as each insertion takes linear time). Scikit-learn estimators that accept sparse matrices will accept any format and convert them to an efficient format internally (usually `csr_matrix`). You can also do the conversion yourself using the methods `tocoo`, `todok`, `tocsr` etc. on `scipy.sparse` matrices.

Or, just use the [`CountVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/feature_extraction.html#common-vectorizer-usage) or [`DictVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/feature_extraction.html#loading-features-from-dicts) classes that scikit-learn provides for exactly this purpose. `CountVectorizer` takes entire documents as input:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
>>> documents = ["The dog ran", "The boy ran"]
>>> vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=0)
>>> vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=0, stop_words=[])
>>> X = CountVectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
>>> X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
>>> X.toarray()
array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1]])
```

... while `DictVectorizer` assumes you've already done tokenization and counting, with the result of that in a `dict` per sample:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
>>> documents = [{"the":1, "boy":1, "ran":1}, {"the":1, "dog":1, "ran":1}]
>>> X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
>>> X.toarray()
array([[ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
>>> vectorizer.inverse_transform(X[0])
[{'ran': 1.0, 'boy': 1.0, 'the': 1.0}]
```

(The `min_df` argument to `CountVectorizer` was added a few releases ago. If you're using an old version, omit it, or rather, upgrade.)

**EDIT** According to the FAQ, I *must* disclose my affiliation, so here goes: I'm the author of `DictVectorizer` and I also wrote parts of `CountVectorizer`.

Comment: Accepted answer because CountVectorizer was the real answer here. (Maybe DictVectorizer too, but I haven't tried it yet.)